# How does $H_{k}=\displaystyle\left[H_{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, harmonic-numbers

I'm confused about one of the algebraic steps,

In showing the $k+1$'th term, we have:

\begin{align}\displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k+1}H_{j} &= \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}H_{j} + H_{k+1}  \\
&=(k+1)H_{k}-k+H_{k+1}\\
&=(k+1)\left[H_{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right]-k+H_{k+1} <----\text{this step} \\
&=\vdots\\
&=(k+2)H_{k+1}-(k+1).
\end{align}

How does $H_{k}=\displaystyle\left[H_{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right]$?

i.e. for $k=5$, $H_{5}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{5}$, but $H_{5+1}-\displaystyle\frac{1}{5+1}=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{6}=0.$

Comment: Are you sure $H_k$ is not the *sum* of the $\frac{1}{\ell}$'s, i.e.  $H_k=\sum_{\ell=1}^k \frac{1}{\ell}$?

Comment: (That is, $H_5\neq \frac{1}{5}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\color{blue}{H_{k}=1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac 1 k}
$$ then
$$
H_{k+1}=\color{blue}{1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac 1 k}+\color{red}{\frac 1{k+1}}
$$ thus
$$
H_{k+1}=\color{blue}{H_k}+\color{red}{\frac 1{k+1}}
$$ equivalently
$$
\color{blue}{H_k}=H_{k+1}-\color{red}{\frac 1{k+1}}
$$